# Second increment of loop overwrites first and so on .

Tags: excel, vba, loops, overwrite

I have been looking at this for to long so I am tossing it to those with more experience then I in hope of a copper or to of knowledge being tossed at me. The code runs with no errors.

The issue is that the second increment of the 1st loop overrides the first increments data range and so on. Loop 1 will populate rows 2:15. If I look at the address of lastrow it will show me the correct range of b16 as lastrow/cell in column to paste to , But as soon as the loop for the next objWorkBook runs it starts overwriting the fist increments cells rather then going to last row. I have a feeling i am missing something silly but it alludes me.

Any help or advice would be appreciated. I am relay interested in feed back. this will eventually process 100+ workbooks each adding roughly 1000 entries. I am concerned about the efficiency of my code. would using arrays speed things up? once things are caught up it will only process 2 workbooks a week. Again thank you for any pointer or advice your willing to share.

```
Option Explicit

Sub parse()

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    'Application.EnableCancelKey = xlDisabled

    Dim strPath As String, strPathused As String
    strPath = "C:\prodplan"

    Dim objfso As FileSystemObject, objFolder As Folder, objfile As Object

    Set objfso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objFolder = objfso.GetFolder(strPath)


    'Loop through objWorkBooks
    For Each objfile In objFolder.Files

        If objfso.GetExtensionName(objfile.Path) = "xlsx" Then

            Dim objWorkbook As Workbook
            Set objWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(objfile.Path)

            ' Set path for move to at end of script
            strPathused = "C:\prodplan\used\" & objWorkbook.Name

            'open WB to consolidate too
            Workbooks.Open "C:\prodplan\compiled\plancon.xlsx"


            'Range management WB
            Dim SRCwb As Worksheet, SRCrange1 As Range, SRCrange2 As Range, lastrow As Range

            Set SRCwb = objWorkbook.Worksheets("plan")
            Set SRCrange1 = SRCwb.Range("b6:i7")
            Set SRCrange2 = SRCwb.Range("k6:p7")

            'Range management destination WB
            Dim DSTws As Worksheet
            Set DSTws = Workbooks("plancon.xlsx").Worksheets("data")

            'start header dates and shifts copy from objworkbook to consolidated WB

            Set lastrow = Workbooks("plancon.xlsx").Worksheets("data").Range("b" & ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

            SRCrange1.copy
            lastrow.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, operation:=xlNone, skipblanks:=False, Transpose:=True
            Range(ActiveCell, Selection.End(xlDown)).Offset(0, -1).Value = objWorkbook.Name


            Set lastrow = Workbooks("plancon.xlsx").Worksheets("data").Range("b" & ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

            SRCrange2.copy
            lastrow.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, operation:=xlNone, skipblanks:=False, Transpose:=True
            Range(ActiveCell, Selection.End(xlDown)).Offset(0, -1).Value = objWorkbook.Name

            'Begin loop to copy content.
            Dim DSTheader As Range
            Set DSTheader = DSTws.Range("d1:bw1")
            Dim SRCheader As Range
            Set SRCheader = SRCwb.Range("a1:a110")

            Dim x As Variant
            Dim y As Variant

            Dim matchEXIT As Boolean
            matchEXIT = False

    For Each x In DSTheader
      For Each y In SRCheader

            Dim SRCrngCP1 As Range
            Set SRCrngCP1 = SRCwb.Range(y.Offset(0, 1).Address & ":" & y.Offset(0, 8).Address)
            Dim SRCrngCP2 As Range
            Set SRCrngCP2 = SRCwb.Range(y.Offset(0, 10).Address & ":" & y.Offset(0, 15).Address)

            If y > 0 Then

            If x = y Then

            Dim MyColumn As String
            Dim Here As String


            Here = DSTws.Range(x.Address).Address
            MyColumn = Mid(Here, InStr(Here, "$") + 1, InStr(2, Here, "$") - 2)

            Set lastrow = DSTws.Range(MyColumn & ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

            SRCrngCP1.copy
            lastrow.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, operation:=xlNone, skipblanks:=False, Transpose:=True

            Set lastrow = DSTws.Range(MyColumn & ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

            SRCrngCP2.copy
            lastrow.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, operation:=xlNone, skipblanks:=False, Transpose:=True

            If x = y Then matchEXIT = True
            If matchEXIT = True Then Exit For

    End If
    End If

        Next y

            matchEXIT = False
    Next x

     MsgBox x
            objWorkbook.Close False

            'Move proccesed file to new Dir
            Dim OldFilePath As String
            Dim NewFilePath As String

            OldFilePath = objfile 'original file location
            NewFilePath = strPathused ' new file location
            Name OldFilePath As NewFilePath ' move the file

        End If
            Set lastrow = Workbooks("plancon.xlsx").Worksheets("data").Range("b" & ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: hard to say for sure without data to run this on, but I can almost gaurantee your problem is with referencing `ActiveCell` in ` Range(ActiveCell, Selection.End(xlDown)).Offset(0, -1).Value = objWorkbook.Name` It's always best to Avoid `ActiveCell` at all costs, unless debugging, and set the cell you want through a variable or some other statement. Just a note of caution without digging too deep

Comment: this code is a beast to go through without any data behind it. Have you tried to step through the code line-by-line at the loop to see what each line is doing that is causing it to overwrite the first loop's data?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have warn out the f8 key.. trying to get this going I will comment out your suggestion and see what I get.

Comment: Any suggestions for alternate code .. ?

Comment: For sure, definitely, 100% use arrays for speed and simplicity. Don't override the index variables, but create transforms instead. For example values from `src(i1,j1)` copied to `dst(i2,j2)` with fixed rules about how `i2` relates to `i1` etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so i figured it out after a nice long weekend away from it. With a Duh moment had

```
 'open WB to consolidate too
            Workbooks.Open "C:\prodplan\compiled\plancon.xlsx"
```

Inside the loop that was suppose to copy to it so at each loop it reset my copy to WB causing what looked like overwriting.

I moved the open line out and the loop increments the paste to last cell with no issue. it did however break

```
 Range(ActiveCell, Selection.End(xlDown)).Offset(0, -1).Value = objWorkbook.Name
```

Well sort of .. If I f8 down the code it works .. if I run the code it skips the line .. I dunno... .I will re post with another Question if I can't figure it out.

Comment: Side note . moving the line out caused the active sheet to go wanking so I just activated the the proper sheet prior to the code.     Range(ActiveCell, Selection.End(xlDown)).Offset(0, -1).Value = objWorkbook.Name

Answer (score 0):

**UNTESTED**

Can you test this and tell me if you get any errors.

```
Option Explicit

Sub parse()
    Dim MyColumn As String, Here As String, OldFilePath As String, NewFilePath As String
    Dim strPath As String, strPathused As String

    Dim objfso As FileSystemObject, objFolder As Folder, objfile As Object

    Dim objWorkbook As Workbook, wbPlan As Workbook
    Dim SRCwb As Worksheet, DSTws As Worksheet

    Dim lastrow As Long, lastrowN As Long

    Dim SRCrange1 As Range, SRCrange2 As Range
    Dim DSTheader As Range, SRCheader As Range, x As Range, y As Range
    Dim SRCrngCP1 As Range, SRCrngCP2 As Range

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    strPath = "C:\prodplan"

    Set objfso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objFolder = objfso.GetFolder(strPath)

    'Loop through objWorkBooks
    For Each objfile In objFolder.Files
        If objfso.GetExtensionName(objfile.Path) = "xlsx" Then

            Set objWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(objfile.Path)
            Set SRCwb = objWorkbook.Worksheets("plan")
            Set SRCrange1 = SRCwb.Range("B6:I7")
            Set SRCrange2 = SRCwb.Range("K6:P7")

            ' Set path for move to at end of script
            strPathused = "C:\prodplan\used\" & objWorkbook.Name

            'open WB to consolidate too
            Set wbPlan = Workbooks.Open("C:\prodplan\compiled\plancon.xlsx")
            Set DSTws = wbPlan.Worksheets("data")
            lastrow = DSTws.Range("B" & DSTws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

            With DSTws.Range("B" & lastrow)
                SRCrange1.Copy
                .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, operation:=xlNone, skipblanks:=False, Transpose:=True
                lastrowN = DSTws.Range("B" & DSTws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
                .Range("A" & lastrow & ":A" & lastrowN).Value = objWorkbook.Name

                lastrow = lastrowN + 1

                SRCrange2.Copy
                .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, operation:=xlNone, skipblanks:=False, Transpose:=True
                lastrowN = DSTws.Range("B" & DSTws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
                .Range("A" & lastrow & ":A" & lastrowN).Value = objWorkbook.Name
            End With

            Set DSTheader = DSTws.Range("D1:BW1")
            Set SRCheader = SRCwb.Range("A1:A110")

            For Each x In DSTheader
                For Each y In SRCheader
                    Set SRCrngCP1 = SRCwb.Range(y.Offset(0, 1).Address & ":" & y.Offset(0, 8).Address)
                    Set SRCrngCP2 = SRCwb.Range(y.Offset(0, 10).Address & ":" & y.Offset(0, 15).Address)
                    If y > 0 Then
                        If x = y Then
                            Here = x.Address
                            MyColumn = Mid(Here, InStr(Here, "$") + 1, InStr(2, Here, "$") - 2)

                            lastrow = DSTws.Range(MyColumn & DSTws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

                            With DSTws.Range("B" & lastrow)
                                SRCrngCP1.Copy
                                .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, operation:=xlNone, skipblanks:=False, Transpose:=True

                                lastrow = DSTws.Range(MyColumn & DSTws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

                                SRCrngCP2.Copy
                                .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, operation:=xlNone, skipblanks:=False, Transpose:=True
                            End With

                            If x = y Then Exit For
                        End If
                    End If
                Next y
            Next x

            objWorkbook.Close False

            OldFilePath = objfile 'original file location
            NewFilePath = strPathused ' new file location
            Name OldFilePath As NewFilePath ' move the file
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry for not getting back to you  sooner. I have ran your alterations it looks like they  paste everything into range b1:c11 continues to overwrite.